# append to state array and add extra object key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

sorry if the title isn't great but what I want to do is this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
      axios.get('http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=xml&results_per_page=9')
      .then((response) => {
        parseString(response.data, (err, result) => {
          result.response.data[0].images[0].image.map((cat) => this.setState({ cats: this.state.cats.concat(cat) }))
        })
      });
    }
```

this function, pulls from catapi, then sets state of my cat state array to every cat object. each cat object has 3 keys from the cat api, how can I add an extra key called `likes` for every array object?

im thinking something like:

```
this.setState({ cats: this.state.cats.concat(cat), likes: 0 })
```

but obviously that doens't work

anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ah done it

just had to add it in like so:

```
result.response.data[0].images[0].image.map((cat) => (                
    cat.likes = 0,
    this.setState({ cats: this.state.cats.concat(cat) }))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

.map() returns an array which I believe means you are returning an array of items calling setState. Without seeing the overall logic I can't be sure exactly what you're doing but I  would probably fetch the data, map it to a new array of objects, adding your key during the map, and lastly setState using the newly mapped array.